# How to detect whether user is in Windows 7 Classic mode or not using Java?

Tags: java, windows-7-x64

I have developed a Java 1.7 stand-alone application which should run only on Windows 7 Classic mode, but not in Basic mode. Right now, this application initially popup a dialog box asking to switch to Classic mode though they are still in Classic mode. Hence, to make things easy I'm planning to detect dynamically using Java whether user is in Classic mode or not.

Please let me know right solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "classic mode" and "basic mode"?

Comment: @Matt the OP probably means with Aero enabled or not... which really shouldn't matter for any app...

Comment: @Malt I mean Windows 7 Classic View/theme.we can switch to classic view by "Right-click an empty space on the desktop and select Personalize.  At the bottom of the panel are a few non-aero schemes, one of which is called classic."

Comment: @SnakeDoc There is one commercial software called Vericut 6.1.2 which works only in Classic view/theme. So, my application triggers that software when needed.